# How to make a site editable vs. readonly depending on Roles.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, readonly, roleprovider

I have a project with many large views (editable forms; think surveys of sorts). The customer, in pilot phase mind you, wants a role that can view all forms and elements, but should not be able to edit/save.

One easy fix would perhaps be to check for a Role and toggle the submit-buttons on/off. But I am hoping there is some decently easy way to transform a view from editable to readonly without entering HTML's @readonly on every element (there is well over thousand elements, ranging from anything from TextBoxFor, EditorFor to Checkbox and textareas).

The project utilizes three roles: Admin, Centre and Patient. In the controller in question I have [Authorize(Roles="Admin,Centre")], but this probably needs to go now (or I need to add Patient) since the latter needs a complete readOnly-access.

Any ideas on how to get this working, without editing every model attribute and/or every razor-editor?

Project uses mvc3, razor, jquery and jQuery-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this old question I'll present the way I solved it.

I had to overload "TextBoxFor", "CheckBoxFor" (etc.), adding a boolean parameter for readOnly/disabled to the end of the methods. Exmaple below:

```
    //Overload TextBoxFor with a "disabled" parameter. For use with readonly-roles
    public static IHtmlString TextBoxForRo<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary();

        if (htmlAttributes != null)
        {
            foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor property in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(htmlAttributes))
            {
                attributes.Add(property.Name.Replace('_', '-'), property.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
            }
        }

        if (disabled)
        {
            attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
    }
```

I had to do this for every type or form-input, and obviously I had to replace a lot of calls in the views. It works though and it was the best solution I could think up.